# Anything inherently undesirable in using browsers native login prompt?

Tags: html, authentication, passwords

It seems like in the past [native login prompts](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/08/25/using-the-browsers-native-login-prompt/) were more popular but are rarely seen now. Is there a reason why they are not used any more? I have heard they are insecure, but never given a good reason as to why (if SSL is not used aren't any inputs taken from the user insecure?). Is the only true difference they cannot be made to look a different way?

Comment: IMO, native login prompts are better if you're trying to stay RESTful -- a login page almost always means a session.

Comment: As far as i know, HTTP-Authentication has no possibility to do a log-out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it's just due to the limited flexibility it gives; you cannot style the native forms, which is a big design problem, and something I doubt many company's would accept. 
Also, in future you might want the login form to have a captcha, or another form element (e.g. Are you on a private computer/ keep me logged in).

Therefore I would recomend using HTML forms for login, but native forms should still be secure if you need to use them for whatever reason